# How can I specify multiple DataTemplate in windows.resources for use by a ContentControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, contentcontrol

How can I specify multiple DataTemplate in windows.resources for use by a ContentControl?
My code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Customer}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" ("/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Occupation}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=")"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use DataTemplateSelector to return the Datatemplate you want to be applied..

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>
```

here MYtemplateselector is `DataTemplateSelector`, in Select() method of selector you can check for the property bound to contentcontrol and return the corresponding Datatemplate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove `x:Key` from `DataTemplate` and try this:

```
<ContentControl Name="CustomerContentControl">
    <local:Customer />
</ContentControl>

<ContentControl Name="PersonContentControl">
    <local:Person />
</ContentControl>
```

In this article, `Josh Smith` show, how to get access the elements that are in the `DataTemplate`:

[How to use FindName with a ContentControl](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/how-to-use-findname-with-a-contentcontrol/)